# SQL Query to loop through

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have two tables `TravelHistory` and `LikesToVisit`.

Both have two fields, `SSN` and `AirportId`.

What is the query to find if a customer has visited all cities he likes to visit?.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you non-distinct list of those who haven't traveled to all of their  likes.

```
SELECT * FROM LikesToVisit AS lv LEFT OUTER JOIN TravelHistory AS th ON lv.SSN = th.SSN AND lv.AirportID = th.AirportID WHERE lv.SSN = NULL
```

Or , alternatively with a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM LikesToVisit AS lv WHERE lv.SSN NOT IN (SELECT SSN FROM TravelHistory AS th WHERE th.SSN = lv.SSN AND th.AirportID = lv.AirportID)
```

Comment: note that using `in` with most DB's is often very slow (especially when dealing with large record sets within the subquery!).  Using joins is typically significantly faster from personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give all the cities which he liked to visit and not visited yet.

```
SELECT SSN, Airportid
  FROM LikesToVisit
MINUS
SELECT SSN, Airportid
  FROM TravelHistory
```

Selecting all the SSN that are not in the above result set will give you the list of people who has visited all he liked

```
SELECT SSN, 'Visited all he liked' 
  FROM Travelhistory 
 WHERE SSN not in (select distinct SSN 
                     FROM( SELECT SSN, Airportid
                             FROM LikesToVisit
                            MINUS
                           SELECT SSN, Airportid
                             FROM TravelHistory)
```